# Loop Subtract and Append in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, subtraction

I am not entirely sure what type of problem this but here it is.

I have 2 data frames (Baskets and Stocks Unwind). My problem requires me to use the Stocks unwind table to locate the matching stock in the basket table and remove the exact number of units from the baskets that are available. I then need the output in a table. The way I need to do this by order of date. Let me use APPL as an example.

I need to remove 100 units of AAPL. I need to choose from my inventory of baskets where to remove AAPL from my first priority is to take from baskets with the earliest date. After the looping procedure I would get 2 tables. A remainder table with all the stock from the Unwind table that were unable to be removed and Basket Table indicating which baskets to unwind from and in which order. In AAPL example my remainder stock table would have 10 units of APPL in it and my basket table would print all three instances of AAPL as it is 90(10+50+30)<100. Note that I cannot Unwind more stock than I have in the Unwind table.

I am quite certain of problem like this exists I am just not sure the name of this type of problem or the correct tags. Any help would be appreciated

The basket table is as follows

```
BSKT | STOCK     | Nominal|  Date
-------------------------------
A    | AAPL       | 10    |  15/05/17
A    | V          | 25    |  15/05/17
B    | MFC        |  5    |  15/05/17
B    | GOOG       | 30    |  15/05/17
C    | AAPL       | 30    |  17/05/17
D    | AAPL       | 50    |  18/05/17
```

The stocks to unwind table is below

```
STOCK | Units
--------------
AAPL | 100       
V    | 15        
GOOG | 20        
MFC  | 5
```

The resulting tables would be as follows

Basket to unwind

```
BSKT | STOCK     | Nominal|  Date
-------------------------------
A    | AAPL       | 10  |  15/05/17
A    | V          | 15  |  15/05/17
B    | MFC        |  5  |  15/05/17
B    | GOOG       | 20  |  15/05/17
C    | AAPL       | 30  |  17/05/17
D    | AAPL       | 50  |  18/05/17
```

Remaining to unwind Table

```
STOCK | Units
--------------
AAPL | 10      
V    | 0        
GOOG | 0        
MFC  | 0
```

Comment: Please put the desired result based on the tables you provided. Also, is the "stock" table at the bottom the same as the unwind table you are referring to?

Comment: @PLapointe updated and edited thanks for the feedback.

Comment: For GOOG, you need to unwind 20 but you have 30 in your initial basket. Why do you still need to unwind 10 in the final unwind? Same comment for V.

Comment: @PLapointe sorry about that got mixed up you are correct I have updated accordingly and also updated the tables so that they make a little more sese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do that with dplyr:

```
basket <- read.table(text="BSKT  STOCK      Units  Date
A     AAPL        10    15/05/17
A     V           25    15/05/17
B     MFC          5    15/05/17
B     GOOG        30    15/05/17
C     AAPL        30    17/05/17
D     AAPL        50    18/05/17",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

unwind <- read.table(text="STOCK  Units
AAPL  100
V     15
GOOG  20
MFC   5",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)

updated_basket <- left_join(unwind,basket,by="STOCK") %>%
group_by(STOCK)  %>%
rowwise   %>%
mutate(to_trade=ifelse(Units.x<=Units.y,
                       Units.x,
                       min(Units.y,Units.x-cumsum(Units.y)))) %>%
ungroup %>%
group_by(STOCK)  %>%
mutate(left_to_trade=Units.x-cumsum(to_trade))

  STOCK Units.x  BSKT Units.y     Date to_trade left_to_trade
  <chr>   <int> <chr>   <int>    <chr>    <int>         <int>
1  AAPL     100     A      10 15/05/17       10            90
2  AAPL     100     C      30 17/05/17       30            60
3  AAPL     100     D      50 18/05/17       50            10
4     V      15     A      25 15/05/17       15             0
5  GOOG      20     B      30 15/05/17       20             0
6   MFC       5     B       5 15/05/17        5             0

updated_unwind <- updated_basket  %>%
ungroup %>%
group_by(STOCK)  %>%
summarise(Units=max(Units.x)-sum(to_trade))

  STOCK Units
  <chr> <int>
1  AAPL    10
2  GOOG     0
3   MFC     0
4     V     0
```

Comment: @P Lapointe I was having issue wit the mutate part of the solutions. Turns Out that my column names were different among tables.

Comment: @P Lapointe will do - I am just playing around with it to see if it works properly with my data. Currently it is not because the column names are not the same I have adjust accordingly. I will update both tags as well as your answer when I get it to work. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: @P Lapointe I am getting the below error Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  incompatible types, expecting a integer vector
In addition: Warning message:

Comment: @mannym Hard to say without looking at your data. Make sure the class is the same as in my example using `str(basket)` and `str(unwind)`

Comment: @P Lapointe I plan to update my question to be more detailed as what I am asking as the the solution you provided works on the small data set above but provides contradictory output when run on my large data set. After I update the question should I un check the answered icon? Sorry I am new to this